# C# Filtering out "Space" key in UserActivityHooks.cs

Tags: c#

I am making my own "Wordpad" type of thing, and I have successfully done it the usual way with a textbox, but now I am trying it with using the "UserActivityHooks.cs" program inside of it. The problem that I am having is when they press the space bar, it prints: HiSpaceMom instead of: Hi Mom. Is there any way to filter it out? I've tried to use this:

```
UserActivityHook hook;
    string log = string.Empty;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        hook = new UserActivityHook();
        hook.KeyUp += (s, e) =>
            {
                log += e.KeyData.ToString();
                if (log == "Space")
                {
                    log = " ";
                }
                textLogs.Text = log;
            };
```

But this method only works when "Space" is alone, and not next to any other characters. Can anyone please help? The source code is here:
http://code.google.com/p/wikipedia-aloud-reader/source/browse/trunk/WikiReader/UserActivityHook.cs?r=4

Comment: I am still not clear what the actual problem is?

Comment: I'm not sure why the word 'Space' shows, which is what you should find out in my opinion. But you can replace it with `log = log.Replace("Space", " ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've provided above, the reason this is happening is because you're checking the *log* for equality with `"Space"`, not the `e.KeyData` object. Ergo, given that you're constantly building the log, the only way `log == "Space"` would ever be true is the first time, if the first character encountered is a space. Thereafter `log == "Space"` will never and can never be true. (Unless the user actually typed in the characters "Space", but that's not something you'd want to convert - further reason to change your design.)

Additionally, you're adding the `KeyData` string to your log before you even check it, so this won't work as is even if you fix your conditional.

Two points on things you can do to fix this:

1. Check whether `e.KeyData.ToString() == Space`, not `log`.
2. You're going to run into performance issues with your log string if you're building a long log. You should be using a `StringBuilder` instead, appending each character to it, and converting it to a `string` when it's time to use or write it. As it stands, you end up creating an entirely new string every time you add a character to it.

So a remedied version of this code might look something like the following:

```
// log is defined above as a StringBuilder
hook.KeyUp += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.KeyData.ToString() == "Space")
    {
        log.Append(" ");
    }
    else
    {
        log.Append(e.KeyData.ToString());
    }
    textLogs.Text = log.ToString();
};
```

One last thing - though this should allow your implementation to do what you'd intended it to, there's some pretty severe flaws in the way it seems like it'll work. What happens if the user wants to delete the word they just wrote, or wants to change the word they wrote 50 characters ago? As it stands, you've made what appears like a perfectly serviceable, if basic, keylogger, but I'm not sure how you're planning to allow the user to do anything but write a single, perfectly-spelled/-formatted string, after which they can't do any editing. (Also - what happens if they press `Control`, or `Shift`, or `Alt`? Are you handling that elsewhere?)